# If two matrices are path connected, so are their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

The set of $n\times n$ matrices can be identified with the space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Let $G \le GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

We say that $A \in G$ and $B \in G$ are path-connected (not sure if this is the correct term) in $G$ if there is a continuous path $\alpha:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\alpha(0)=A$, $\alpha(1)=B$ and $\alpha(t)\in G \forall t\in[0,1]$.

I want to show that if $A$ and $B$ are path-connected in $G$, so are $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$.

Here is my proof:

So let us define $\beta:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by
$$\beta(t)=(\alpha(t))^{-1}$$

Then $\beta(0)=A^{-1}$, $\beta(1)=B^{-1}$, and $\beta(t)\in G \forall t\in[0,1]$.

So we only need to show that $\beta$ is continuous.

I noticed that
$$\beta(t+\delta)-\beta(t)=\beta(t+\delta)\left[\alpha(t)-\alpha(t+\delta)\right]\beta(t)$$
(Eq. 1)

Now here is the step I am not sure.

If I can then write
$$||\beta(t+\delta)-\beta(t)||\le||\beta(t+\delta)||||\alpha(t)-\alpha(t+\delta)||||\beta(t)||$$
(Eq. 2)

Then let
$$M=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}||\beta(t)||$$
and then $\forall \epsilon$, because $\alpha$ is continuous, $\exists \delta$ s.t.
$$||\alpha(t+\delta)-\alpha(t)||<\frac{\epsilon}{M^2}$$
and hence
$$||\beta(t+\delta)-\beta(t)||<\epsilon$$
and it's done.

Anyone can tell me how to go from Eq.1 to Eq.2? Any other thing wrong with my proof?

Comment: Although you have not asked for different solutions but you could just use that $A \to A^{-1}$ is continuous, right? Then $\beta$ trivially is continuous. Where this fact is essentially the same as observing that the function **det** is continuous, since you may know that $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(A)} adj(A)$.

Comment: How to show that $A \to A^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Your proof looks good at a first glance (provided you know the norm of a product is no larger than the product of the norms in your setting), though perhaps you mean "$t + \delta$" throughout rather than "$t + \delta t$"?

Comment: @Mathaholic: Do you know the formula $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(A)} adj(A)$? Since if I remember correctly this is something one learns probably in a second year course on linear algebra. Look at the definition of $adj(A)$ and observe easily that $A \to adj(A)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me, although I would consider instead the path $\gamma(t)=B^{-1}\alpha(t)A^{-1}$, which looks a bit cleaner. Anyway, to go from eq. 1 to eq. 2, just take any *submultiplicative* matrix norms on both sides, such as the operator norm $\|A\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$ or the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2}=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)}$.

Comment: So the Frobenius norm is just the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?. And it can be shown to be submultiplicative?

Comment: @Mathaholic Yes. It's easy to find a proof online or from any book that discusses matrix norms. Basically, the submultiplicativity of Frobenius norm follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Let $a_{i\ast}$ denotes the $i$-th row of a matrix $A$. Then $|a_{i\ast}x|^2\le\|a_{i\ast}\|_2^2\|x\|_2^2$ for any vector $x$ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality). Therefore $\|Ax\|_2^2\le\|A\|_F^2\|x\|_2^2$ and $\|AX\|_F^2\le\|A\|_F^2\|X\|_F^2$ for any square matrices $A$ and $X$.